# Does it make sense to create more reducers than nodes we have?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

So main think with good reduce phase is good partition distribution. But for example we can't control it, or do not know how to do this(we don't know our data).

Is the big amount of reducers will increase chances of better per reducer data distribution?
What is common practice in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is usually evenly distributed among reducers using modulus hash partitioning.  That means (effectively) that the hash of the key is divided by the number of reducers, and the remainder is the index of the reducer that the value gets sent to.  For example, if the hash of your key is 47269893425623, and you have 10 reducers, 47269893425623 % 10 = 3, so the 4th reducer (remember, 0-indexed) gets that record.

If your records have hot-spot keys, meaning that a large percentage of the values have exactly the same key, then adding reducers will probably not help (you'll just be adding overhead- all of those keys will still go to the same reducer).

If you do not have that situation, then adding reducers may help.  Just remember that there is a network copy stage between mapper and reducer.  The more that you split up the reducers, the more copying needs to be done between the mappers and reducers, so that part of the job will get slower.

Comment: 'The more that you split up the reducers, the more copying needs to be done between the mappers and reducers, so that part of the job will get slower.' -- I disagree with this. More data isn't being sent over... it's the same amount of data just being split up more. If anything, it'll make it go faster because you are parallelizing the network movement more.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the number of reducers is in some ways more of an art than a science. You just have to try out different things to see what works best for your particular job.

In general, I see a couple of major options:

- 1-2 reducers -- this is good for jobs with a small amount of output where it's convenient to just have a few files coming out to make post-processing more efficient
- 95% of the reduce slots on the system -- this will fully utilize your cluster for both medium-sized and large MapReduce jobs. You want to use 95% so that you don't block smaller jobs from finishing.
- 190% of the reduce slots on the system -- this is only for extremely large jobs and doesn't need to be used too often.

Increasing the number of reducers will only help so much. In a mathematical sense, presume all of your keys are evenly distributed except for `hotkey`. Then, your reducer distribution, given `hotkey` is 100MB and everything else is 100MB (to be extreme). If you have two reducers, you will have approximately reducer 1 with 150MB and reducer 2 with 50MB. With three reducers, you'll have 1 reducer with 133MB (100MB + 33MB), and the other two with 33MB. With 100 reducers, you'll see one with 101MB and all the rest with 1MB. As you can see, increasing the number of reducers doesn't really help much, but it does help a little bit. Probably not enough to really spread it that thin.

---

Hotspots are not going to be a problem for many jobs. The default partitioning behavior is completely reasonable for giving you a relatively even spread.

If you do have a hotspot that you are trying to squash or a very skewed data set, you can write a custom partitioner to write special rules for which reducer the data goes to. For example, if you know you have three keys that are hot spots, you can write a partitioner that sends key1 to reducer 1, key2 to reducer 2, key3 to reducer 3, then sends everything else to other reducers.